# In Mathtype, how to reduce space above a character?

Tags: mathtype

In Mathtype 7.4.2, how could I reduce the space above the "1" in this example?

Do you see the lost space above the "1"? I want the line closer of the "1"...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Either you configure the spacing in the MathType settings -- you are interested in the *limit height* or the *embellishment gap* --, as explained in the link below:

https://docs.wiris.com/en/mathtype/mathtype_desktop/reference?s[]=define&s[]=spacing#define_spacing_dialog

2. Or you manually move the character object as you wish with the *Nudge* tool. Refer to the following link for more information:

https://docs.wiris.com/en/mathtype/mathtype_desktop/basic_tutorials?s[]=nudge#making-fine-adjustments

Comment: Your second option is great! I'm really happy to discover this features of Mathtype. Thanks for this!

Comment: For the second option, I had never seen all these options before in the "define spacing" window. I had never seen the scroll bar at this place ... It's fantastic all these options. Thank you very much for that!

Comment: The "limit height" is not the option to remove the margin above a single character. I don't find the way to remove this default margin above any character. Any solution?